# Triggering a callback in compiled javascript

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I have a bit of a challenging problem. I'm using the Blogger JSON API to get JSON data and display on the page. Normally it's very straightforward:

```
    <script src="http://blog-name.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=renderPost&amp;max-results=4"></script>
```

You embed this script on a page which requests the data and passes a data object to the javascript callback (in this case the callback is called `renderPost`).

The problem is that I am using the Closure compiler to compile the rest of my JS. So, `renderPost` is obfuscated.

How would you go about mimicking this behavior with javascript? Can you use an AJAX request to get the JSON object?

Part of the problem is I don't really know what Blogger is doing here, so an explanation of that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), you can export the variable as follows:

```
window['varname'] = varname;
```

For example:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
window['renderPost'] = renderPost;
function renderPost(name) {
    return prompt('', '');
}
```

compiles to:

```
window.renderPost=a;function a(){return prompt("","")}a();
```

instead of (when omitting `window['renderPost'] = renderPost`):

```
prompt("","");
```

Comment: PS. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export).

Comment: Works! Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), and this is currently the only way to get json from other domain. No, you cannot use regular ajax request for cross-domain communication. See Rob W answer on how to solve your problem.